# How see contents of my azure drive?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage

I'm training with Azure environment and I have some trouble with the object [CloudDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive).

I have mounted a drive on a blob (on the Storage Emulator) but I can't see it with a GUI as CloudBerry or Azure Storage Explorer.

If I understand properly this topic [client-side-accessing-windows-azure-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474056/client-side-accessing-windows-azure-drive), the blob which store the driver data looks like an other blob ?
So if the drive is really create, I can see him with CloudBerry ?

Other linked question :
Did you know a GUI which can upload page blob  (and not block blob) ?

To create my CloudDrive I use this web site : http://archive.loicrebours.fr/index.php/2012/01/29/azure-storage-drive-55/
(but it's a french web page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the storage emulator, the cloud drive is simulated using local storage on your disk. To see its contents, you can open the storage emulator and choose to view cloud drive contents (which opens an explorer window to the correct temporary directory). See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_exploringwindowsazurestoragevs2010_topic5.aspx) for more details.

Note: The Windows Azure Drives lab is also in the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396).

Comment: Thx a lot, "Storage Emulator UI -> File -> Open Azure Drive Folder in Windows Explorer" is the way I searched ! And thx for the tutorial link.

Comment: Just letting you know, those links don't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The cloud drive is simply a VHD stored in your storage account as Page Blob. Like David explains, if you're working in the emulator the cloud drive is simulated. But if you run the application in Windows Azure the VHD file will be present in your storage account (I assume you'll be able to see it in CloudBerry, but I don't know if it supports page blobs).

I don't know if there's a GUI allowing you to upload page blobs, but there's a [**console application**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/11/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs.aspx) that allows you to upload VHD files as page blobs like this:

**vhdupload.exe input-file http://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/container/blobname key.txt**

Comment: thx too. I have see a console application, but you can't upload on storage emulator with it. But I couldn't see blob with CloudBerry, and I see it with Explorer on storage emulator, I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

ClumsyLeaf CloudXplorer uploads page blobs nicely, so it's a good way to get your VHD into blob storage to use as a Drive.

Comment: Thx for this UI, maybe it may upload page blob but it don't display my .vhd. David solution is still the only I know now. (I still work on my emulator for information.)

Comment: To be clear, my answer was to this question: "Did you know a GUI which can upload page blob (and not block blob)?"